# Issues in finding out the last row in excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying this code to find out the last row-

`msgbox objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).EndXL(up).Row`

But i am keep getting this error-

`Object required: Rows`

Comment: Mattboy has given you the main error. Besides that you have to fully qualify the `Rows` See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba EDIT: Are you doing this from within Excel? I have a feeling that you are using vbscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim oXLApp, wb, ws

'~~> Define xlUp
Const xlUp = -4162

Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oXLApp.Visible = True

'~~> Open file. Chnage path as applicable
Set wb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

With ws
      MsgBox .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Also notice the use of `Worksheets` rather than `Sheets` See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929344/exporting-some-sheets-from-excel-workbook-to-pdf/14929890#14929890) for explanation.

Comment: finally...i just need to define xlup to make my code run..thanks sid!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

It's just your End(xlUp) part that's wrong

Comment: I tried this code..but now it is giving an error, subscript out of range...what does it mean?I am using vbscript..

Comment: Hmm... try changing it to `Sheets(1).Rows.Count`. That's what I think Sid means with fully qualifying Rows.

Comment: I tried this -objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Sheets(1)Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row..but it is getting an error type mismatch-Sheets

Comment: You're missing a  `.` between Sheets(1) and Rows, I don't suppose that's it? Otherwise I'm stumped here. It works fine from Excel, but I'm not so familiar with vbscript, sorry.

Comment: still giving the same error...i corrected everything but still getting the same error- object required rows

Comment: @Praveenks: Seems like you missed my question in the above comment. Are you using VBA (from within Excel) or vbscript?

Comment: @Praveenks: Aha... I was expecting your answer below my comment. Anyways, I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
dim last as integer
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
last = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
```