# How to use formular1c1 without defining the range in vba excel?

Tags: vba, excel

My code is:

```
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1c1 = "SUM(R[2]C:R[4157]C)"
```

My problem is what if I have more than 4157 rows. How do I ensure all rows for that column will be added up?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14934653/1698517) to familiarize yourself with `xlUp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1c1 = "=SUM(R[2]C:R[" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count & "]C)"
```

EDIT:

Added the `=` to the formula, so that Excel understands it is a formula. Otherwise it would just put the text in the cell.

Comment: The above code does the same thing except it doesn't pick up all of the rows. This is what I get (SUM(R[2]C:R[52]C). The previous code comes up with this: SUM(R[2]C:R[53]C)

Comment: I edited the answer. I didn't notice your original code didn't have the `=` in the formula.

Comment: Good! If you think this (or any other) is the correct answer, then mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As per Jaycal's comment try this:

```
dim rowNum as integer
Range("M1").Select
rowNum=activesheet.cells(rows.Count,activecell.Column).end(xlUp).row
ActiveCell.FormulaR1c1 = "=SUM(R[2]C:R[" & rowNum & "]C)"
```

where using the cells notation means we can refer to row then column, row is taken as the max rows in worksheet, column is the active cell - which makes this a bit more reusable than referrring to range("M" & rows.count) given you've selected the cell anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But now, it doesn't give me the SUM, just the formula. What do I need to add?

Comment: whoops, I missed an equal sign inside the formula, I'll edit and add.